# Copying the values of one sheet to multiple spreadsheets in multiple folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that copies the data from one sheet and pastes it in another sheet in another spreadsheet. However, I want to paste the data in multiple spreadsheets that I have saved in multiple folders (with childfolders) and in those spreadsheets the sheet that I want to paste already exists but it is outdated. I would like to retrieve the google sheets spreadsheets from every child folder and paste the updated data in the same sheet in all of them.
This is the code that I have:

```
function copy_end(){

var carpetas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('carpetas');  
var pegar = SpreadsheetApp.OpenbyId("ID").getSheetByName('carpetas'); //here I would like to paste the data to the sheet carpeta in multiple spreadsheets 
  var firstrow= 0;
  var lastrow =carpetas.getLastRow();
  var rows= lastrow-firstrow;
  var Range = carpetas.getRange(1,1,rows,4);
  var DataCopied = Range.getValues();

  // I defined the variables for better understanding      
  var startRow = pegar.getLastRow()+1; // +1 because remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = DataCopied.length;
  var numColumns = DataCopied[0].length;
  pegar.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(DataCopied);
}}
```

Does anybody know how I can add the multiple folders to the script? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How about putting the folder ids in an array? Or list them in a sheet and read them from there?

Comment: How many levels of folders do you have? You have a series of parents folders, and the spreadsheets can be either there or under the folder's immediate children, or there is an indefinite number of levels in the folder tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

Assuming that there are two levels of folders (the parent folders and their immediate children), I'd suggest the following workflow:

- Get an array of parent folder ids (`folderIds` in the sample below).
- For each folder id, get the corresponding [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) and get its subfolders via [Folder.getFolders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfolders). Get all those subfolders as well as their parent folder in an array.
- Iterate through the array of the subfolders and their parent folder, and look for spreadsheets located in any of these, using [Folder.getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype).
- For each resulting spreadsheet, try to get its `carpetas` sheet. If it exists, copy your desired values (this is the part of the script you already had).

#### Code sample:

```
function copy_end(){
  const folderIds = ["FOLDER_ID_1", "FOLDER_ID_2"]; // Add your parent folder ids
  const carpetas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('carpetas'); 
  const firstrow = 0;
  const lastrow = carpetas.getLastRow();
  const rows = lastrow-firstrow;
  const Range = carpetas.getRange(1,1,rows,4);
  const DataCopied = Range.getValues();  
  const startColumn = 1;
  const numRows = DataCopied.length;
  const numColumns = DataCopied[0].length;
  folderIds.forEach(folderId => {
    const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    const subfoldersIter = folder.getFolders();
    const folders = [parentFolder];
    while (subfoldersIter.hasNext()) {
      folders.push(folders.next());
    }
    folders.forEach(folder => {
      const filesIter = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
      while (filesIter.hasNext()) {
        const file = fileIter.next();
        const fileId = file.getId();
        const pegar = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId).getSheetByName('carpetas');
        if (pegar) {
          const startRow = pegar.getLastRow()+1;
          pegar.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(DataCopied);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: hii! this is exactly what i needed thank you so much :) it timed out because there's over 200 folders to go through but other than that it's great!